# Extendable way to select nth lowest/highest members of a list in python when there is a rank tie

Tags: python, list, rank

Working on a hacker rank challenge and feel like I really hacked it.  Need to select the second lowest members of a list, and return both if there's a tie.  Here's what I did:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    names = []
    scores = []
    names_scores = []
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        names.append(name)
        scores.append(score)
        names_scores.append([name, score])

def second_smallest(numbers):
     m1 = m2 = float('inf')
     for x in numbers:
         if x <= m1:
             m1, m2 = x, m1
         elif x < m2:
             m2 = x
     return m2
 
second_smallest_number = second_smallest(set(scores))

second_lowest_name_score = filter(lambda x: x[1] == second_smallest_number, names_scores)

second_lowest_names = [item[0] for item in second_lowest_name_score]

second_lowest_names.sort()

if len(second_lowest_names) == 1:
    print(second_lowest_names[0])
else:
    print(second_lowest_names[0] + "\n" + second_lowest_names[1])
```

My issue with this is that even though I "passed" I'd have to write a new line of the if statement for every number of ties.  I would like to know a way that this would be extensible no matter the nubmer of ties.  I understanding I could `pandas` `rank()` but wondering how to do this with the standard library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `itertools.groupby` to group the identical scores:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> def second_lowest(scores):
...     ranks = (g for _, g in groupby(sorted(scores)))
...     first = list(next(ranks))
...     if len(first) >= 2:
...         return first  # second lowest is also tied for first lowest
...     return list(next(ranks))  # otherwise return second lowest rank
...
>>> second_lowest([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3])
[1, 1, 1]
>>> second_lowest([1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3])
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

For a more general-purpose function (i.e. get the nth-lowest) you could keep a count of how many individual scores you'd iterated over and return whatever group the nth score landed in.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what we ended up doing:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    scores = []
    names_scores = []
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        scores.append(score)
        names_scores.append([name, score])

from collections import Counter

scores = sorted(Counter(scores).items())

second_lowest_score = scores[1][0]

names = sorted([name_score[0] for name_score in names_scores if name_score[1] == second_lowest_score])

print("\n".join(names))
```